# Struggling with setting an independent path inside a script to call another script

Tags: bash

The following files reside in a certain directory:

```
path/to/file.sh
path/to/file2.sh
```

It works to call `file2.sh` within `file.sh` as follows:

```
path/to/file.sh
. ./path/to/file2.sh
```

but when the files are checked out in another dir:

```
src/path/to/file.sh
src/path/to/file2.sh
```

file.sh cannot find file2 anymore

Possible solution

A possible is to check whether a certain dir exists

`path/to/file.sh`

```
if [ -d "src" ]; then
  . $PWD/src/path/to/file2.sh
else
  . $PWD/path/to/file2.sh
fi
```

but when the files are checked out in another directory this will break again.

Question

What solution will work independently on the directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
source "$(dirname -- "$0")/file2.sh"
```

to source `file2.sh` located in the same directory as the calling script.